# Using fgetl in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file

I'm having trouble fixing this `fgetl` in MATLAB. When I run this it gives the following error:

> File day 1 is missed ?!
>   Error using fgets
>   Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
>
> Error in fgetl (line 32)
>   [tline,lt] = fgets(fid);
>
> Error in LK_onedaydata1 (line 41)
>      tline = fgetl(fid);

Please find below piece of my code:

```
directory = '/C/Users/default.default-PC/Documents/PAMGuide/PAMGuide/LK_20sept2018/';


    idepth = 001; %the folder that lists all the .wav files%


     path2data = [directory num2str(idepth,'%03i') '/'];

        work = dir(path2data);

        if(numel(work)==0)
            disp(['>>>>>>>>>> File day ',num2str(idepth),' is missed ?!'])
        else
            disp(['File day: ',num2str(idepth),' has ',num2str(numel(work)),' data!'])
        end


    fid = fopen([directory '001/listing.txt'],'r');
       tline = fgetl(fid);
           ii = 0;
       while (tline ~= -1)
                if (length(tline) == 0)  
                   continue
                end
                ii = ii + 1;
                file_names(ii,:)=tline;  % create file names in matlab data worksapace
                year(ii) = str2num(tline(4:7));
                month(ii) = str2num(tline(8:9));
                day(ii) = str2num(tline(10:11));
                hour(ii) = str2num(tline(13:14));
                min(ii) = str2num(tline(15:16));
                sec(ii) = str2num(tline(17:18));
                tline = fgetl(fid);
       end   
       fclose(fid);
       timestamp = datenum(year,month,day,hour,min,sec);
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message, MATLAB always gives a lot of helpful information in there. You have one `end` to many in your code, which would be more obvious if you were to indent your code properly (please [edit] your question and fix the indenting, it's hard to read this code as it is now).

Comment: You should also check the return value of `fopen`. If `fid` is -1, the file could not be opened. You need to test for this before you use the file identifier.

Comment: See? There you have it: the error message says "Invalid file identifier." That means that `fopen` was not able to open the file. Maybe you misspelled the name, maybe it's in a different directory?

Comment: but the directory i specified is correct one. not sure whats wrong! yes fid is giving a value of -1

Comment: Do `dir([directory '001/listing.txt'])` and see what you get. Or maybe use `path2data` instead of `directory`? Could also be a permissions thing. Check to see that you can open that file for reading?

Comment: it still shows same error. I tried what you suggested Cris

Comment: its fixed. it was the backslash syntax that I messed up in windows as I was always coding in linux machines. lol

Comment: Look into `fullfile`. Don’t type slashes.

Comment: sure will do. thanks.